# Cyclic animation and compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have set a cyclic animation(it repeats itself) and I've done the compositor settings.
I want to change some compositor settings but after first repeat of animation.
Second repetition of animation will have for example different color. 
So that I don't have to make another renderlayer and change it with new settings.
Can I set somehow the renderlayer so that it renders at different time with different compositor settings?

I hope I was clear.

Comment: save it as a different file? or you could copy your scene and add the new compositor settings.

Comment: If I would do that I would have to glue videos together. That not very good idea.  I want cyclic animation so that I can chage time of the cycle. It's bound to the scene to work for smooth transition due to other modifiers.